# Issues with running lmer on multiple columns stored in a dataframe

Tags: r, lme4

[image]I have a data frame with 10 subjects each of which has multiple angle movement measurements repeated 5 times at year 0 and 1. The Entire data is in long format and I am trying to find the difference between year 0 and 1, because there are multiple measurements for each subject I am trying to use the lmer function.

I used the follow code but keep getting an error. Any help would be appreciated.

```
# define the formula for lmer
lmer_formula <- formula(". ~ year + (1|subject)")

# define the function to apply lmer to each column in a data frame
lmer_function <- function(df, cols) {
  lmer_results <- list()
  for (col in cols) {
    col_formula <- as.formula(paste(col, deparse(lmer_formula)[2], sep = "~"))
    lmer_result <- lmer(col_formula, data = df)
    lmer_results[[col]] <- lmer_result
  }
  return(lmer_results)
}


# apply the lmer function to each data frame in the list for all columns
cols <- names(FAI_amb_Study)[7:length(names(FAI_amb_Study))]
lmer_results <- lmer_function(df = FAI_amb_Study, cols = cols)
```

> Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) :    invalid model
> formula in ExtractVars

Comment: Please post your data sample as text rather than as an image ... ?  You should look at `?lme4::refit.merMod`: it's an easier way to do what you want ...

Answer (score 2):

`refit` is a convenient (and faster) way to refit a model with different response variables, provided the rest of the model is the same.

```r
## set up structure for results
lmer_results <- list()
## response variables to consider
cols <- names(FAI_amb_Study)[7:ncol(FAI_amb_Study)]
## formula for first model
form1 <- reformulate(c("year","(1|subject)"), response = cols[1])
## fit first model
lmer_results[[1]] <- lmer(form1, data = FAI_amb_Study)
for (i in 2:length(cols)) {
  ## refit first model with successive columns as response
  lmer_results[[i]] <- refit(lme_results[[1]], 
                             FAI_amb_study[[cols[i]]])
}
```